# How do questions actually convert to community wikis?

Tags: support, questions, community-wiki

I stumbled upon this question which, aside from being in need of some cleaning up, is not "answerable" as much as it's an open community wiki.

[Common statistical tests as linear models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303269/common-statistical-tests-as-linear-models)

How do users convert questions to community wikis?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow your point about the referenced thread. The answer to your question *here* is that regular users can't convert Qs to CW. You have to flag the Q & the moderators do it.

Comment: @gung my point is that the gist of the question is "what named tests are just formulations of linear regression models?" and he names the t test and anova as two examples. There are many possible answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular users cannot convert *questions* (whole threads in practice) to community wiki.  That was once possible, but hasn't been for several years.  You can convert your own answer to CW, but that won't make the question CW or the other answers.  If you believe a thread should be CW, you have to flag the question and ask the moderators to do it.  Just click on the light gray "flag" at the bottom left of the question body, and comment that the Q should be CW and why you think so.